# /clear items with data tag not working on bukkit servers

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-bukkit

Trying to make something on my bukkit 1.8.7 server that detects a nether star in an inventory named "Nut Gem" with the lore "Gem used to summon Nut", which will then try to remove the nether star from your inventory.  For some reason it will not clear the item I need it to, but it does clear any normal nether stars. I am using

```
/clear @a nether_star 1 0 {display:{Name:"Nut Gem",Lore:["Gem used to summon Nut"]}}
```

Now found out that this is a problem with bukkit!  Not sure why but it works in single player but not in bukkit servers(at least this version).  Any info on how to fix this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You have unbalanced brackets in the NBT data; add an extra `}` onto the end:

```
/clear @a nether_star 1 0 {display:{Name:"Nut Gem",Lore:["Gem used to summon Nut"]}}
```

If that still doesn't work, it may be because a server mod/plugin's `/clear` command is being used instead of the vanilla one. You may be able to use this instead to force it to use the vanilla command:

```
/minecraft:clear @a nether_star 1 0 {display:{Name:"Nut Gem",Lore:["Gem used to summon Nut"]}}
```

Comment: Sorry! I wasn't able to directly copy the command from the command block.  I've double checked and the brackets are balanced.  Tried your command as well and it still only cleared normal nether stars.

Comment: @Yee Added additional solution that should work based on the information that the command is only not working on Bukkit servers.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused by a plugin overriding the default /clear command. Try replacing /clear with /minecraft:clear and see if it works.